# NavigationComponents onBackPressed works for the system backpress only

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I need to show a dialog when I press back from my fragment, it works for the system backbutton bar doing this

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback {
            showDialog()
        }
```

but, its not poping on `navigateUp()` click

I have tried

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return when(navController.currentDestination?.id){
        R.id.nav_fragment1 -> {
            showDialog()
            false
        }
        else -> navController.navigateUp()
    }
}
```

But it also does not work, any Idea how to get the two working with the same code ?

Comment: Can you explain your problem again: so you want this behavior:
User clicks on the back button (system or on screen?) -> dialog pops up ?
If I understood correctly, it works with system button, but not with button onscreen? Add a listener for your back button on screen, and call function for dialog in it.

Comment: no, the app has two back buttons, on is the upButton and the other is the onBackPressed button provided by the android system, currently it just works for the system back button but not for the upbutton

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code block :

```
  binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            when (navController.currentDestination?.id) {
                R.id.nav_fragment1-> {
                    if (onBackPressedDispatcher.hasEnabledCallbacks())
                        onBackPressedDispatcher.onBackPressed()
                    else
                        navController.navigateUp()
                }
                else -> navController.navigateUp()
            }
        }
```